# Redirect output logs of javax.xml.ws and com.sun.xml.ws

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jax-ws

I am working on a SOAP based web service, with *Sun's Metro*.

I am facing an annoying bug, each time I send a malformed SOAP object to my web service, sun's api spam the System.out with logs like this:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.istack.XMLStreamException2: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'type' must appear on element 'object'.
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.pipe.AbstractSchemaValidationTube.doProcess(AbstractSchemaValidationTube.java:206)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.pipe.AbstractSchemaValidationTube.processRequest(AbstractSchemaValidationTube.java:175)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:106)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:91)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:54)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:555)
>       at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:527)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:119)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:349)
>       at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:321)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: com.sun.istack.XMLStreamException2: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'type' must appear on element 'object'.
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.StAXSource$1.parse(StAXSource.java:185)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.StAXSource$1.parse(StAXSource.java:170)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:127)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.pipe.AbstractSchemaValidationTube.doProcess(AbstractSchemaValidationTube.java:204)
>       ... 20 more

I would like to switch off this log or redirect it to my *error/warn/debug.log* files used by log4j.

I tried to add a rule in my *log4j.xml* file :

```
<category name="javax.xml.ws">
 <priority value="error" />
</category>
```

It didn't worked.

So I tried the following trick:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException").setLevel(
            java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
```

it didn't worked neither.

Any ideas ?

It is not a big issue but it makes my *catalina.log* getting bigger & bigger and it's not the appropriate place for this kind of log.

Chris

Comment: I am investigating the Metro source for a similar problem.  It appears that output to System.out is hardcoded and cannot be easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

Worst-case scenario solution:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("debug.log")));
```

Comment: Thanks Chris
In my case I should use System.setErr instead of System.setOut

If i don't find a better solution I'll go for this one